# How to interact with <body> tag from iFrame

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, browser

Say I have a code like this :

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
 <body>
      <iframe>
          <script>
   //execute javascript here to append another piece of javascript in parent body tag
          </script>
      </iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

Now I want to execute some javascript in that iFrame to append another piece of javascript in parent body tag.

Answer (score 1):

If the iframe belongs to the same domain of the main window, you can simply do

```
top.functionToBeCalled(argument);
```